# Division false in javascript

Tags: javascript, integer

Here if I check wrd and errors they shows 59 and 9, but out put of this function is also 9%,
Please help.

```
function alrt(){
     var ela   = $.trim($('textarea').val());  
     var wrd = ela.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;

     var g_errors= $('.hiddenGrammarError').length;
     var s_errors= $('.hiddenSpellError').length;
     var errors = g_errors + s_errors;
     var ratings = Number(errors)/(Number(wrd));
     $('#show').html('<br> Ratings '+ ratings +'%');
 }
```

Comment: What are you asking? `9/59 = 0.153`, is that not what you are getting?   Where does `9%` come from? Also the `Number(x)` part should be needed, both `wrd` and `errors` should already be numbers.

Comment: @Dexpras I would display the numbers in #show just to verify that they are in fact what you think they are.

Comment: It shows as number if I put wrd or errors replacing ratings (ex: 59 and 9)

Comment: @amccormack but in above it is also 9.

Comment: Also, `ela.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length` can be simplified to `ela.split(/\s+/).length`.

Comment: @MattBurland yep but it out puts wrong values.

Comment: Try to reproduce this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's actually happening.

Comment: @p.s.w.g It is a grammar and spelling checker with rating system, so It may not possible.

Comment: @Dexpras: Then it might not be possible to help you because nothing in your post suggests what the problem might be. Simple arithmetic in Javascript works, so something else is going on. Try breaking your problem down to a simple test case that you can post in a fiddle.

Comment: Also try attaching a breakpoint so you can examine the actual values while the code is running.

Comment: If I use `var ratings = 9/(Number(wrd));` or `var ratings = Number(errors)/59;` it gives correct value for ratings.

Comment: I tried to implement a short part ing fiddle. But I was unable to do so. http://jsfiddle.net/MCKQD/1/

Comment: @Dexpras Here you go. This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/MCKQD/2/ (and produces the expected result).

Comment: @p.s.w.g thank you very much, could you please specify the fault.

Comment: @Dexpras: The problem with your fiddle was that you didn't include jQuery.

Comment: Oh I'm not that familiar with fiddle, but still it does not work on my localhost. I included the jQuery there.

Comment: @Dexpras Well I don't know. The math in the fiddle looks correct. It outputs 0.2222 which is 2/9. (although you have a percent sign after it, so you probably meant to multiply by 100)

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, I remove it here for easiness.